# How to allow systemd-resolved to listen to an interface other than loopback?

Tags: systemd, dns, docker, systemd-resolved

systemd-resolved is a daemon that, among other things, acts as a DNS server by listening IP address 127.0.0.53 on the local loopback interface.

I would like to let the daemon listen to another interface. My use-case is to expose it to docker containers, so that docker containers share the DNS caching provided by systemd-resolved. I know how to configure the host as a DNS server for docker containers, but at least by default, systemd-resolved rejects these DNS queries because they are not coming from the loopback interface, but from the docker bridge interface.

With dnsmasq (a tool similar to systemd-resolved), I did this by [adding `listen-address=172.17.0.1` to the configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998099/dns-not-working-within-docker-containers-when-host-uses-dnsmasq-and-googles-dns/50001940#50001940). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a systemd-resolved equivalent.

Since systemd-resolved is the default at least on Ubuntu 18.04, I would like a solution that works in this configuration.

Is there a way to configure which interface systemd-resolved listens on?

Comment: What is your use-case? I mean, why are you employing `systemd-resolved` as a stub resolver? There are any number of established, purpose-made alternatives, including but not limited to `bind`, `dnsmasq`, `unbound`, etc.

Note that this is not a rant or mindless hate on the systemd suite. I'd just like to know what prompted you to pick this particular service. Is there any functionality the others don't offer?

Comment: My use case is to have docker that "just works" on my machine and on typical people's machine (e.g. my students, as I'm a teacher). I didn't pick systemd-resolved: my distro (Ubuntu) picked it for me when I upgraded (to 18.04). I can uninstall systemd-resolved and re-install dnsmasq (which I had before), but that's a rather intrusive solution, and in particular not a solution I'd recommend lightly to anyone (for example, I tried installing dnsmasq without uninstalling systemd-resolved. My package manager happily accepted and then my machine went berserk eating 100% CPU for nothing ...).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I guess the question changes from "why did _you_ pick systemd-resolved" to "why did _the Ubuntu mantainers_ pick systemd-resolved". It seems clear that, at the very least, packages `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved` should have a `breaks` relationship. And again, why did the distro maintainers make that choice? Seems rather intrusive.

Answer (score 15):

You can't. As cristian-rodríguez mentioned above, it was strictly designed to provide services to loopback only.

Not even an alternative solution using `net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1` + iptables NAT (such as https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost), https://superuser.com/questions/594163/how-do-i-route-a-port-range-in-a-linux-host-to-a-guest-vm), and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580637/iptables-redirect-from-external-interface-to-loopbacks-port) will work, since systemd-resolve explicitly inspects if the destination is outside the loopback network. See the code below for `static void dns_stub_process_query(Manager *m, DnsStream *s, DnsPacket *p)`

```
    if (in_addr_is_localhost(p->family, &p->sender) <= 0 ||
        in_addr_is_localhost(p->family, &p->destination) <= 0) {
            log_error("Got packet on unexpected IP range, refusing.");
            dns_stub_send_failure(m, s, p, DNS_RCODE_SERVFAIL, false);
            goto fail;
    }
```

A workaround is to use `socat` to listen at your docker interface, and forward it to systemd-resolved. The line below does the trick. If required, alter it to listen to TCP:

```
socat UDP-LISTEN:53,fork,reuseaddr,bind=172.17.0.1 UDP:127.0.0.53:53
```

Comment: Apparently this changed. Now we seem to have the `DNSStubListenerExtra` directive at `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` that `Takes an IPv4 or IPv6 address to listen on`. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolved.conf.html#DNSStubListenerExtra=

Comment: @TCB13 Can't get this to work on Debian Buster/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Switching to unbound probably

Comment: @RayFoss that's because systemd/resolved in Debian is an old version that doesn't support `DNSStubListenerExtra` yet. Yes, I'm also waiting for it ;)

Comment: @TCB13 it runs on 127.0.0.53 which makes it easy to ignore when I stalling unbound/DNSMasq. Turns out my issue wasn't DNS related, instead my ISP was doing Deep packet inspection and blocking domains from CDN's with a low reputation. Incredibly annoying what it took to figure that out.

Comment: @RayFoss when your ISP does DPI you know it's time to get a VPN.

Comment: Nice trick, thanks! I will have to use it until Fedora 34 comes out with this brand new feature.

Comment: Note, this `DNSStubListenerExtra` change was introduced in version 247 https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/NEWS#L1455. Check your system with `systemctl --version`.

Comment: Update: `DNSStubListenerExtra` is now available in Debian 11!

Answer (score 13):

Resolved is not intended nor designed for your use-case, but to provide services in the local loopback, thus the listen address is hardcoded.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it seems you are right: the code does [setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "lo", 3)](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/4d09e1c8bab1d684172b1f277f3213825b30d2d9/src/resolve/resolved-dns-stub.c#L425-L427)

Answer (score 13):

Exactly the desired configuration of listen-addresses is freely possible since systemd-resolved [version 247](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/releases/tag/v247) (commit [1f05101f](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/1f05101f) and follow-ups) by setting `DNSStubListenerExtra`.

Address, port, and protocol (tcp/udp) is configurable multiple times. It's even possible to disable the default listener at (tcp/udp) 127.0.0.53:53 by setting `DNSStubListener` to false.

The systemd-resolved configuration-file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` shows this in it's comments – for instance in ubuntu impish (21.10).

```
# systemd --version
systemd 248 (248.3-1ubuntu8)
...

# man resolved.conf
...
DNSStubListener=
       Takes a boolean argument or one of "udp" and "tcp". If "udp", a DNS stub resolver will listen for UDP requests on address 127.0.0.53 port 53. If "tcp",
       the stub will listen for TCP requests on the same address and port. If "yes" (the default), the stub listens for both UDP and TCP requests. If "no", the
       stub listener is disabled.

       Note that the DNS stub listener is turned off implicitly when its listening address and port are already in use.

DNSStubListenerExtra=
   Takes an IPv4 or IPv6 address to listen on. The address may be optionally prefixed with a protocol name ("udp" or "tcp") separated with ":". If the
   protocol is not specified, the service will listen on both UDP and TCP. It may be also optionally suffixed by a numeric port number with separator ":".
   When an IPv6 address is specified with a port number, then the address must be in the square brackets. If the port is not specified, then the service
   uses port 53. Note that this is independent of the primary DNS stub configured with DNSStubListener=, and only configures additional sockets to listen
   on. This option can be specified multiple times. If an empty string is assigned, then the all previous assignments are cleared. Defaults to unset.

   Examples:

       DNSStubListenerExtra=192.168.10.10
       DNSStubListenerExtra=2001:db8:0:f102::10
       DNSStubListenerExtra=192.168.10.11:9953
       DNSStubListenerExtra=[2001:db8:0:f102::11]:9953
       DNSStubListenerExtra=tcp:192.168.10.12
       DNSStubListenerExtra=udp:2001:db8:0:f102::12
       DNSStubListenerExtra=tcp:192.168.10.13:9953
       DNSStubListenerExtra=udp:[2001:db8:0:f102::13]:9953
...
```

*This is an explicit answer for easy reference. [@TCB13](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23085/tcb13) already stated it as a comment.*